# Cell references for Conditional Formatting in LibreOffice Calc using the "Formula is" condition

Tags: conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

In Libreoffice Calc 7.6, I want to have cells that do not contain a number to have a certain style ("error"). If the value has a comma instead of a point as the decimal separator: `1.5` vs `1,5` . The function `ISNUMBER(<cell>)` does return TRUE on the first and FALSE on the second example.

So I am trying to use conditional formatting to achieve this. I choose "Formula is" and then enter the formula `NOT(ISNUMBER())`. That does not work obviously, because the function does not know what cell should be looked at. the formula `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())`gets the very cell address. So I am trying to use `NOT(ISNUMBER(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))` for this, but this happens to apply to *every* cell. In turn, doing `ISNUMBER(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))` does not apply to any cell.

What is wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about using [**Ctrl+F8**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/03080000.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=.uno:ViewValueHighlighting#bm_id3145068)? Yes, the “Error” style is bright and beautiful, but in order to distinguish a number from a non-number, black and blue colors are enough, isn’t it?

Comment: Assuming G1 is the first cell to format conditionally, just add that address to the ISNUMBER() function, so it's ISNUMBER(G1). LO will adapt the cell reference for other cells accordingly. You can extend the formatting rule to other cells in different ways: (1) by selecting the cells before you define the conditional format; (2) Menu Format -> Conditional -> Manage, select the formatting rule, adapt the cell range; (3) Copy formatting usinng paste special.

Comment: @tohuwawohu sticking to the top-left cell only works well and seems to be the correct answer, as `#libreoffice:matrix.org` confirms. please post an answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply conditional formatting based on the "Formula is..." condition to a range of cells, the easiest way is as follows:

1. Select the cell range where the conditional formatting should apply (in this example, let's assume it's "G1:G10";
2. Menu Format -> Conditional -> Condition...;
3. In the "Condition 1" box, select "Formula is";
4. In the text box, enter your formula **referencing the first selected cell**, in your case `NOT(ISNUMBER(G1))`
5. Select the style to apply if the formula evaluates to `TRUE()`, hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

LibreOffice will adapt the formula in the cells "G2:G10" silently and automatically.

If your cell range isn't coherent, you may use the "Paste Special" feature:

1. Starting from the example above, select and copy "G1".
2. Select a different cell or cell range, e.g. "D6:D12".
3. Open the "Paste Special" dialogue:

   - either do a right-click into the selection and select "Paste Special" from the context menu;
   - or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
4. From the "Presets" at the left, select <kbd>Formats only</kbd>.